# Does God lie? And does the devil tell the truth?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, satan, adam-and-eve, deception

The Bible quotes God assaying:

> And the Lord God commanded the man, saying, "You may freely eat of every tree of the garden; 17 but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall die."  (Genesis 2:15-17)

The Bible goes on to quote Eve and the serpent talking:

> 3 but God said, 'You shall not eat of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, neither shall you touch it, lest you die.'" 4 But the serpent said to the woman, "You will not die. 5 For God knows that when you eat of it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil." 6 So when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was a delight to the eyes, and that the tree was to be desired to make one wise, she took of its fruit and ate; and she also gave some to her husband, and he ate. 7 Then the eyes of both were opened, and they knew that they were naked; and they sewed fig leaves together and made themselves aprons. (3:3-7)

Now the devil tells Eve that she will not die and that she will gain the knowledge of good and evil. Which happens from what the Bible describes. God also specified that they will die on the day that they touch the tree, which does not happen, so it wasn't truth that God told Eve. Even if God said it as a metaphor, it was a metaphor that neither Adam nor Eve understood, because Eve told the serpent they they will surely die. And God is all-knowing, so he had to know that they will misunderstand him.  So, he deliberately told a metaphor, which he knew was going to be understood literally, and he knew it would be taken as literal interpretation.

In either way God provided Eve with misleading information. (It could be a possibility that something is lost in translation, but if not, it would take interpreting the text completely opposite to what is written in order to come to a different conclusion - and if we do, then why bother taking the rest of the Scripture as it is written?)

Does this mean that we must redefine our definition of lying? 
Maybe lying excludes lying to children for example to save them from a greater harm 
(like taking drugs for example)

If something is too complicated to explain to a child, maybe the Bible suggests that it's OK to lie to them. I feel like a lot of parents already do that making up stories to keep their children from making noise in church (for example). Telling them that if they misbehave the ghost will get them etc.

Or maybe lying overall means something else in the 10 commandments. 
I really wonder about that, because I see situations when it might be good to tell a lie. 
I'm Polish, so I always think of the story If I was holding a Jew in my house and Nazis would come in asking if I had any Jews in the house. I know that I couldn't tell the truth.

So I just wonder If God lied?
If so, is lying sometimes ok according to this passage?
If God doesn't lie, then what is the definition of lying?
If God told the truth that they would die, then is devil lying that they will not die?

I'm only interested in the Catholic perspective of this scripture as I was raised Catholic and this question bothered me for most of my life.

Comment: Despite my answer in which I pick out three "faulty premises," I still +1d this as a good question.  Theology often involves uncovering hidden premises and exposing them.  Please don't be offended.  Welcome to C.SE!

Comment: Also, I hope you are not offended that I chose to answer even though techincally I come from a slightly different tradition.  I would argue, however, that my perspective will match up with what you are expecting.  Again, as stated in the answer, feel free to ignore it if you would prefer a properly dogmatic response.  There are several Catholics on the site, and I think they'll vouch for where I'm coming from.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that you seem to be trying to treat Christianity as a set of rules, where if you define the rules well enough and follow them to the letter, you will be OK. Christianity isn't like that.

Comment: @DJClayworth Christianity is much more then just a set of rules. And possibly not all Christianities have rules that they follow to the letter. Some however teach what rules a good Christians follows and if those rules are not really defined then its impossible to follow those rules.

Comment: I think a better question might be why the tree was there in the first place. Just curious if God put the tree there for the same reason why I leave poisoned cookies on my kid's table.

Comment: You're asking two questions.

Comment: I am not speaking Hebrew language. Therefore I don't know how exactly the sentence is written in the original. However one translation I know, does not translate with "you will die on that day", but "on that day it will be sure that you **will** die". And according to the Bible, Adam and Eve had to die after having taken from the tree.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not necessarily a Catholic perspective, but I suspect the exegesis would pass muster.  (Feel free to ignore if you wish)

**Faulty Premise #1: God is lying**

God did not lie. In the day she ate of it, she became subject to death. Her body (and Adam's) began to decay, and went from immortality to mortality.

Additionally, she and Adam were, in fact, separated from God *which is a type of death*.

This question has specifically been asked, [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/what-is-the-specific-meaning-of-die-in-genesis-2) and there is more to the explanation.

In short, most priests would disagree with the premise that God is lying.

**Faulty Premise #2: The Devil is incapable of telling the truth**

Although the Devil is "the Father of Lies," it does not follow that the Devil is incapable of telling truth (or at least using Truth) when it suits his purposes.  The Devil's aim is to deceive, not to lie.  He deceived Eve by suggesting that God was lying (see above) and that God was withholding something "good" from her.  Neither was the case.

In general, it is often said that every lie contains a truth, if only so that someone will believe it.  If I knew that everything the Devil said was false, for example, I could always discern the truth by negating what he said.  Simple Logic - Everything A becomes !A.  Ergo truth.  Again, not the Devil's problem.  The Devil merely deceives and destroys. If he can use accuracy to get there, he will use it.

I have little doubt that a Priest would agree with me on this.

**Faulty Premise #3: Honesty is the supreme value**

(Here is where I become a Protestant again), the highest duty of man is to love.  As [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/marital-relations-and-lying) shows, our duty is to love.

When the Nazis were clearing the Ghetto, they might have asked, "Are there any Jews here?"  A Christian could rightly "lie" and say "No," simply by re-framing the question in higher terms - "Are there any Jews here whom we may kill?"  No, you may not kill them, since love bids me to protect them. If I must lie, then that too is a sin - but being unloving is worse.

Again, here, I *suspect* that most RC Priests would accept this premise, but I defer to Roman Catholics to weigh in on that.

In summary, God isn't lying, the Devil is still deceiving even when he appears to be telling the truth, and we are under no obligation to answer deception in the terms handed to us.

Comment: Although I have a rather checkered history prior to being received into the Catholic Church, I can't see anything wrong here. One might perhaps recommend C S Lewis's *Screwtape Letters* in support of Point 2.

Comment: Funny thing is, I was exactly thinking of Screwtape when I wrote that :)

Comment: for a direct answer in scripture, Hebrews 6:18 comes to mind, but I'm not sure if that applies to all of God's actions and statements, or just those two specific oaths he made to Abraham. the context is somewhat difficult for me to parse

Comment: Regarding your last point, which @Trig [lambasted in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6615954#6615954) some folks are OK with lying for the greater good, some are against it. There was a good debate on the [Chesterton Blog](http://www.chesterton.org/2011/05/gilbert-magazine-we-quarrel-you-decide/) about this concerning LiveAction's covert ops into planned parenthood.

Comment: @AffableGeek Nice answer. Also God is not a baby-sitter, just do as he commands, whether you understand it or not

Comment: Definition of death is not beginning to decay nor becoming mortal. "a permanent cessation of all vital functions; the cause or occasion of loss of life". On the second premise I did not make a point that devil is incapable of telling the truth just that if God didnt lie then devil would have to as they said opposite things. On your third point you say that it is ok to lie sometimes which is what i would understand to be true but never really heard anybody say. Yet I dont like how you say to re-frame a question that just like pretending and you can do that for anything.

Comment: Still it does answer my question so I'll mark it as best answer until a better answer appears.

Comment: @xitcod13 yeah, I didn't like my last point either. I initially wrote that in the middle of a 24 hour migration. I've backed off that point and reworked it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know...maybe death is more than a simple cessation of physical life.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek yes. Death can also be understood as a passage from this life to another. When we are resurrected to become an immortal being. But nowhere does death mean loss of immortality. Once you die you cannot die again unless you come back to life. Since Eve and Adam eventually do die so they did not die after eating a fruit. Plus changing words definitions explains nothing.

Comment: particularly agree with point 2. The Devil often warps the truth or tells "part-truths"

Comment: @AffableGeek The person who trusted in God was like Eleazar and the seven brothers and their mother, God, as Jesus promised, would give them what to say at that moment. Examples that come to mind: Jesus on paying taxes and St. Jeanne D'Arc at trial. *re-framing the question in higher terms* appears to be the kind of mental gymnastics forbidden by the 7th commandment, incumbent on all not just Catholics. Possible answer to the Nazis: *'If the Jews were here and I were to tell you they were, you would kill them.; and if I were to refuse to tell you, you would kill me ...'*

Comment: regarding #3, Catholics will never say lying is moral (it might be a grave issue or not depending on theologians) but allow for the possibility of mental reservation. Even to purse love in its truest sense, one may not commit anything which is intrinsically evil (as lying is)

Comment: Good answer, but I feel it could be improved on two points: 1) The example given about the devil seems to be used almost like an example of him telling the truth, but in the example itself, he was lying. 2) In the example about the Holocaust, when it says, *A Christian could rightly "lie" and say "No," ...* (this is a great example up to this point btw), it then seems to turn around and start portraying a very conflicting message right after that, and the sentence itself doesn't seem to flow after that point.

Answer (score 3):

The first scripture that comes to mind is that God cannot lie nor can he repent (i.e. change) ([Num 23:19](http://bible.us/1/num.23.19.kjv)). The next one that comes to mind is that Satan has no truth in him ([Jn 8:44](http://bible.us/1/jhn.8.44.kjv)).

Finally, though it is less accepted, they did in fact die in the day they sinned because  God's time is much different than ours ([2Pe 3:8](http://bible.us/1/2pe.3.8.kjv)). One thing to note to support the aforementioned notion is that no man has lived to see 1,000 years. The oldest man in The Bible, Methuselah, lived to be 969 years old. ([Gen 5:27](http://bible.us/1/gen.5.27.kjv))

Comment: Definitely a possibility. The bible doesn't record Eve's age when she died, but Adam lived 930 years (not quite 1000!)

Comment: @NickRolando it is impossible to know the age of every person in Biblical History.  I think here one may refer to Hebrews 9:27 "And as it is appointed unto men once to die, but after this the judgment."

Answer (score 3):

God cannot lie:  [Numbers 23:19](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Num&c=23&t=KJV#19), [Titus 1:2](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Tts&c=1&t=KJV#2), Heb 6:18

The first link is the word of God directly given to Balaam who was summoned by the king of Moab out of fear regarding the encampment of Jews near them and the possibility of war with them.

The second is written by the apostle Paul in the preamble to his epistle to Titus.

The third is from body of Paul's epistle to the Hebrews.

All are direct and unequivocal in their statements that plainly God does not lie.

The fact that God knows all truth and does not lie is a bedrock foundation for Christians.  Our own faulty processes of reason and emotion which help us understand the world around us but through which we can make mistakes in our understanding because of our own limitations even though we are led by the Holy Spirit in our lifelong search to understand and follow the truth of God's word is a human quality.  The fact that we lie is a human quality.  God should not be seen through the lense of these two fallibilities of humans.

God knows all truth and knows all the world and the universe he created from their beginning to their end.  And, unlike our own fallibility, God is infallible and not only has the capability to never lie to us but according to these clear declarations simply does not.

If God were to lie to us it would water down his message and make the truth as revealed to us by him confusing to grasp and we would always be wondering - did God lie about that?  What was the truth from God, and what was a lie?

We can know with comfort and peace that God has and will always speak the truth to us.  It is from this bedrock foundation of knowledge of the absolute truth of the revelation of God that we can indeed have infant-like faith in his Word.  That faith is indeed the ultimate foundation not only of our relationship with God but of our very salvation through Christ.

We can also take comfort in his promises, or covenants, with us.  We can know that the promise to Noah as symbolized by the rainbow to never again send a flood to destroy most of the world would be honored as long as this temporal universe exists.  We can know that the covenant with Abraham that his people would become numerous as the sands and be a blessing to all nations will never be broken by God.

Most importantly we can know that his free gift to us of salvation by grace through faith in Jesus Christ, taken as our Lord and Savior which leads to eternal life in Heaven, is a pure and absolute gift with no possibility of withdrawal by God for anything we might do, however bad (except the one exceptional sin of blaspheming the Holy Spirit).

Comment: is it because he doesnt have a facebook account?

Comment: I agree the verses you point out are relevant, but we're looking for for a little more than this from answers around here. Can you [edit] and add some explanation here? If you don't, this will likely be removed as it doesn't meet any of [our guidelines for good answers](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/30).

Comment: @Caleb I have fixed this post according to what you have said.  This is my first post.  I apologize for my initial brevity.

Comment: @aeoril That's more like it! That edit just made a non-answer into an excelent answer. Welcome to the site by the way. Have you had a chance to check out the [faq] or peruse the [important stuff on meta](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq)? Those might help you get an idea about what's going on around here. I realize it's more than a little different from your usual online forum.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you very much for your very kind words. I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know denominational or traditional perspectives, but God didn't deceive or mislead Eve. Eve lacked faith in God. She did in fact die on that day; whether it was a spiritual death (probably more likely how God meant it), or her body started the decaying process and died in a [day](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20peter%203:8&version=AMP) in the eyes of God (as mentioned by BigM).

We (or at least I) am not at liberty to say when lying is okay, even if you think it will save someone's life (not necessarily saying I wouldn't do so..), because, in a sense, it might also lack faith.

The bible does not teach us to lie and scare our children into obeying and behaving. They should just obey and, if appropriate, tell them the truth of why in a way that they can understand. The bible teaches us to discipline our children (moderately) to obey and behave.

> Foolishness is bound up in the heart of a child, but the rod of discipline will drive it far from him.
>   Prov. 22:15
>
> Withhold not discipline from the child; for if you strike and punish him with the [reedlike] rod, he will not die.
>   Prov. 23:13
>
> The rod and reproof give wisdom, but a child left undisciplined brings his mother to shame.
>   Prov. 29:15

In those verses the devil told them they would have the knowledge of good and evil, which was true. Also a demon tells the truth of Jesus' identity in [Mark 1:24](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark%201:24&version=AMP)

> What have You to do with us, Jesus of Nazareth? Have You come to destroy us? I know who You are—the Holy One of God!

Answer (score 1):

"Now the devil tells Eve that she will not die and that she will gain the knowledge of good and evil. Which happens from what the Bible describes."

So Eve is still alive today?  She is not, she died thousands of years ago, despite the devil claiming she and Adam would not die.

They both did, so the devil lied.  I find it hilarious how certain people go to great lengths to try to spin that God lied, whle it is clear that the devil DID lie, and yet they still claim he did not.

Answer (score 1):

Adam and Eve spiritually died that day - the moment they sinned and forfeited their holy status before God.

Rejecting God's fellowship is **just** as equivalent and awful as death.

That's the whole point of Christianity.  To be born again and make dead men alive through the grace of Jesus Christ.

John 3:1-21

> 3 Now there was a man of the Pharisees named Nicodemus, a ruler of the Jews. 2 This man came to Jesus[a] by night and said to him, “Rabbi, we know that you are a teacher come from God, for no one can do these signs that you do unless God is with him.” 3 Jesus answered him, “**Truly, truly, I say to you, unless one is born again[b] he cannot see the kingdom of God**.” 4 Nicodemus said to him, “How can a man be born when he is old? Can he enter a second time into his mother's womb and be born?” 5 Jesus answered, “Truly, truly, I say to you, unless one is born of water and the Spirit, he cannot enter the kingdom of God. 6 That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit.[c] 7 Do not marvel that I said to you, ‘You[d] must be born again.’ 8 The wind[e] blows where it wishes, and you hear its sound, but you do not know where it comes from or where it goes. So it is with everyone who is born of the Spirit.”

Ephesians 2:4-5

> But because of His great love for us, God, who is rich in mercy, 5 made us alive with Christ, even when **we were dead in our trespasses**. It is by grace you have been saved.

Without the blood of Jesus Christ, we are really just walking pieces of flesh.  Even worse, this flesh once had honour and prestige yet all of it was forfeited, to lust after lowly garbage.  Just like Esau.

Answer (score 1):

I think two scriptures will answer your question for you:-

1

> NWT Titus 1:1, 2 "Paul, a slave of God and an apostle of Jesus Christ according to the faith of God’s chosen ones and the accurate knowledge of the truth that is according to godly devotion 2 and is based on a hope of the everlasting life that **God, who cannot lie,** promised long ago;..."

2

> NWT John 8:44 "You are from your father **the Devil**, and you wish to do the desires of your father. That one was a murderer when he began, and he did not stand fast in the truth, because **truth is NOT in him**. When he speaks the lie, he speaks according to his own disposition, because he is a liar and the father of the lie.

God cannot lie and Satan cannot tell the truth.